# Class subscript cannot call value of non-function type

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to implement a subscript feature on a class construct. The non a revelent code of the class has been removed.

```
class Grid {

    var nodes: [[Node]]? = nil

    subscript(row:Int, column:Int) -> Node {

        get {
            return self.nodes[row][column]
        }
    }

}

let grid = Grid()
let node = grid(row:0, column:0)
```

The last line of the code shows following issue :

> "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Grid'"

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use square brackets for subscript.  This works in the playground:

```
class Grid {
  var nodes: [[Int]] = [[1],[2],[3]]

  subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Int {
    get {
      return self.nodes[row][column]
    }
  }
}

let grid = Grid()
let node = grid[0, 0]  // node == 1
```